# Is there a clear path by which I could implement a React Component that uses context extensively in ScalaJS + React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, porting, scala.js

[This component from `react-sticky` is one of two in the library.](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky/blob/master/src/sticky.js)

- `container`, which initializes and passes down a `context` to its `child`...
- `sticky`, which uses the `context` and scroll position to achieve a sticky header effect.

I just spent about two hours or more porting this laboriously into `ReactJS` in `scalajs` and I've pasted below what I have done thus far. It doesn't compile; there are still loose wires.

I'm starting to think that I should give up because maybe my path is not a good one. What I tried to do is to eliminate the use of `context` which is unavailable in the `sjs` library with a `ParentProps` and pass its state to the child and back.

However given the number of moving parts involved I am losing faith that this may even work. I need to know whether there is a better approach or not to porting.

```
package shindig.frontend.component.layout

import fr.iscpif.scaladget.mapping.ace.PlaceHolder
import japgolly.scalajs.react._
import japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom._
import japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.prefix_<^._
import org.scalajs.dom.html.Div
import org.scalajs.dom.window
import org.scalajs.dom.raw.ClientRect

import scalacss.Defaults._

object StickyComponent {


  case class Props(
                    isActive: Boolean                   = true,
                    className: String                   = "",
                    style: Seq[StyleA]                  = Seq(),
                    stickyClassName: String             = "",
                    stickyStyle: Seq[StyleA]            = Seq(),
                    offsetTop:   Double                    = 0,
                    offsetBottom: Double                   = 0,
                    stickyStateChange: () ⇒ Callback    = () ⇒ (),
                    contextProps: StickyContainer.Props = StickyContainer.Props()
                  )

  case class State(isSticky: Boolean = false, origin: PlaceHolder)

  class Backend($:           BackendScope[Props, State]) {

    def componentDidMount(): Unit = {

    }

    def getNode: TopNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode($)
    def getRect          = getNode.getBoundingClientRect()
    def getY             = window.pageYOffset

    def getOrigin(y: Double): Double = getPlaceholderRef.top + y
    def getPlaceholderRef = $.refs.apply[Div]("placeholder").get.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect()
    def getProps: Props  = $.props.runNow()

    def isBelow(y: Double, contextProps: StickyContainer.Props): Boolean =
      y + contextProps.offset >= getOrigin(y)

    def isAbove(y: Double, contextProps: StickyContainer.Props, offset: Double): Boolean =
      contextProps.offset <= contextProps.bottomOfRectOrNil - offset

    def isStickyAt(y: Double, origin: Double): Boolean = {
      val props = getProps
      val y = getY
      props.isActive && isBelow(y, props.contextProps) && isAbove(y, props.contextProps, props.offsetBottom)
    }

    def update() = $.setState(State(

    ))

  }

}

object StickyContainer {

  case class Props(
                    node: Option[TopNode] = None,
                    offset: Double = 0,
                    rect: Option[ClientRect] = None
                  ) {
    def bottomOfRectOrNil: Double = rect match {
      case Some(r) ⇒ r.bottom
      case None ⇒ 0
    }
  }

  case class State(
                    node: Option[TopNode] = None,
                    offset: Double = 0,
                    rect: Option[_] = None
                  ) {
    def withNode(node: TopNode) =
      State(Some(node), offset, rect)
  }

  class Backend($: BackendScope[Unit, State]) {

    def componentDidMount(): Unit = {
      $.modState(_.withNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode($)))
    }

    def render() = {
      <.div(
        $.propsChildren()
      )
    }

  }

  val component =

    ReactComponentB[Unit]("StickyContainer")
      .initialState(State())
      .backend[Backend]($ ⇒ new Backend($))
      .renderBackend
      .build

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two answers really: the first answer is, I still don't know how you might use `context` within `scalajs` wrt `reactjs`, but the second answer is, it didn't matter, and since this time I've ported like ten other small `react` libs without issue. I was focusing on porting methods I did not need to port.

All you need to do is follow the guide at https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-components/blob/master/doc/InteropWithThirdParty.md . If you have been searching for a while you probably already saw this and maybe didn't believe it would work (I didn't quite grasp that it would work at first), since all you're doing is copying `Props` and creating a faux constructor. Well, that's all you need to do - in all likelihood - so try porting only what is required on that page before tackling this task.